# React-native build failed with undefined symbol _RCTInjectedAssertFunction

Tags: ios, react-native

I build my project with the following tools.

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.41.2
XCode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)
```

But I got an error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_RCTInjectedAssertFunction", referenced from:
      -[RCTWebSocketExecutor executeJSCall:method:arguments:callback:] in libRCTWebSocketDebugger.a(RCTWebSocketExecutor.o)
      -[RCTWebSocketExecutor dealloc] in libRCTWebSocketDebugger.a(RCTWebSocketExecutor.o)
  "__RCTLogFormat", referenced from:
      -[RCTWebSocketExecutor initWithURL:] in libRCTWebSocketDebugger.a(RCTWebSocketExecutor.o)
      -[RCTWebSocketExecutor webSocket:didFailWithError:] in libRCTWebSocketDebugger.a(RCTWebSocketExecutor.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong? Something in the build settings?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qo00.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, delete `ios`, `android` and `node_modules` folder from the project directory.
Then run,
 `npm install react-native upgrade react-native link`

This works for me.

react-native link is not supported anymore, instead, you can use `npx react-native-asset`

Comment: Thank u for your help. May be some module depend on different version react-native and link it different static lib to cause this error.